# ¿Por qué no han agregado aún la etiqueta Symfony3?

Tags: soporte, etiquetas

No tengo la reputación suficiente en el sitio para agregar nuevas etiquetas, por eso pongo aquí la pregunta:

¿Por qué no han agregado aún la etiqueta `Symfony3`?

Tengo una pregunta que hacer sobre dicho framework y no la he hecho aún esperando que agreguen la etiqueta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crea tu pregunta y ponle las etiquetas correspondientes. Si necesitas agregar una etiqueta, puedes poner una bandera a tu pregunta con la opción **reportar** y elegir la última opción donde puedes describir el problema con tu pregunta. En este caso, el problema sería agregar una etiqueta a la pregunta. Un moderador se hará cargo de ello y marcará tu reporte como útil.

Que las etiquetas no sean limitantes para seguir publicando contenido fresco y nuevo en el sitio.

Comment: Gracias!! No sabía que se podía hacer de esa forma